# Elements in the lanthanide and Actinide series

Tags: elements, periodic-table

How many elements are there in lanthanide and Actinide series? My big doubt is does the 57th element Lanthanum and 89th element Actinium include in it? [image: Click for the question I got]

In some periodic table the entire 57-71 is given outside the box but in some of them only 58-71 is given outside the box.

Answer (score 0):

The arrangement of elements in periodic table is a subject of debate. There is no particular arrangement which is the best. This is the reason of confusion.

However, Concise Inorganic Chemistry by J.D. Lee mentions:

> These four elements [Sc,Y,La,Ac] are sometimes grouped with the 14 lanthanides and called collectively the 'rare-earths'. This is a misnomer because the scandium group are d-block elements and the lanthanides are f-block elements.
>
> <sub>Pg 677, Concise Inorganic Chemistry, J.D. Lee, Blackwell Science Ltd, 1996.</sub>

So you can consider that the lanthanide and actinide group each contains 14 elements and Lanthanum and Actinium are d-block elements.

Comment: Couldn't it be a 15 in Lanthanide series and 15 in actinide series? Because chemical property is the period function of the atomic number.