Periodic Table Group 3 Period 6, 7
I am studying Periodic Table and have doubts in the group 3 (III-B) periods 6 and 7.

If f-block is not a part of d-block, then why so they place inner transition metals in the boxes of group 3 periods 6, 7?
Since they place so, why are sometimes La and Ac placed while sometimes Lu and Lr are placed? (are these 2 sets of elements part of Group 3, even if the other inner transition elements in between are not!?)
Are all the other f-block elements in between the extreme element La and Lu, or between Ac and Lr, part of the Group 3? (regardless of whether this is anomaly because they are not part of d-block)


https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/87464/elements-in-the-lanthanide-and-actinide-series https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37266/why-is-lutetium-part-of-the-lanthanide-series https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/10478/why-lanthanides-and-actinides-are-shown-separate-from-standard-periodic-table-la

I can at least answer your first question, 1). The periodic table developed by Mendeleev is an incredibly useful tool for predicting the physical and chemical properties of elements, but you must understand that it has limitations. I linked the wikipedia page on the history of the periodic table. The page under "Mendeleev's predictions and inability to incorporate the rare-earth metals" is a quick summary of why the periodic table arranges lanthanoides and actinoides the way it does. It also has plenty of links for further reading. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_periodic_table#Mendeleev's_predictions_and_inability_to_incorporate_the_rare-earth_metals
